# key is not available as prop in the Child component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a parent component in which below component is producing dynamically in **map** function as below:

```
const renderListing = this.props.listing.map(function(list, index) {
        return (
          <Listing
            key={index}
            title={list.title}
            totalWorkers={list.totalWorkers}
          />
        );
      }, this);
```

In this `<Listing />` component, I have a **Checkbox** from `react-md` as below:

```
import { Checkbox } from "react-md";
class Listing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
<Checkbox id="`listSector-${this.props.key}`" name="list-sector" />
   );
  }
}
```

I wanted to give the **props** named `key` concatenated with `id="listSector-0" , id="listSector-1"` and so on.

I have tried string-literals but all invain.

Can anyone know that how to give dynamic `this.props.key` concatenated with `id` of the `checkbox` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'key' and 'ref' are reserved words that are not allowed to be passed as props. You can pass another prop with the same value

```
const renderListing = this.props.listing.map(function(list, index) {
    return (
      <Listing
        key={index}
        keyId={index}
        title={list.title}
        totalWorkers={list.totalWorkers}
      />
    );
  }, this);
```

and use it like

```
<Checkbox id="`listSector-${this.props.keyId}`" name="list-sector" />
```

Comment: Can you clarify *why* `key` isn't passed as a prop? It seems like an arbitrary restriction. (I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16272) to try to get some clarification on this.)

Comment: @mindplay.dk, Why key isn't passed as a prop is because its been used by react internally to optimize on re-renders. Now imagine a case where key was passed as a prop and you try to change the value of key and in the child components componentDidUpdate or the useEffect hook(depending on whether you use class or component based approach) you try to take and action only to realise that the component is not re-rendered but remounted would confuse you. And its safe to not confuse users with such behaviors by imposing a small restriction on not using a name as key

Answer (score 1):

> Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however, there are two special props (ref and key) which are used by React, and are thus not forwarded to the component.

[Special Props Warning – React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)